# What is the difference between declaring variable separately or at a time in Java classes?

Tags: class, variables, declaration

I have declared member variables of a class in 2 separate way:

```
Class MyClass
{
 int x,y;
}

Class YourClass
{
 int x;
 int y;
}
```

What is the difference between these two declaration?

Comment: The first one uses one line of text and the second one uses two lines of text.

Comment: ...and of course, `x` and `y` can have different types in the second example. ;-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a problem and very well explained in all the languages that support both of these syntaxes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between two approach.

First approach data type is common for all of its variable.

For readability second approach look nice.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any difference technically.

But it is choice of programmer to declare as how he/she feels is comfortable to read. Second choice would be more readable when you have numerous fields (POJOs) where could easily get lost reading the elements :)